# An equivalent condition of $f$ is integrable over $R\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, summation, supremum-and-infimum

$\def\hl#1#2{\bbox[#1,1px]{#2}}
\def\box#1#2#3#4#5{\color{#2}{\bbox[0px, border: 2px solid #2]{\hl{#3}{\color{white}{\color{#3}{\boxed{\underline{\large\color{#1}{\text{#4}}}\\\color{#1}{#5}\\}}}}}}}
\def\verts#1{\left\vert#1\right\vert}
\def\R{\mathbb{R}}$
$\box{black}{black}{}
{Question}
{\text{Suppose that $R$ is a rectangle in $\R^2$.}\\
\text{Prove that a function $f:R\to\R$ is integrable if and only if}\\
\begin{align}
\inf\left\{\iint_RgdA:g(x)\ge f(x)\text{ for all }x\in R\right\}
=\sup\left\{\iint_RhdA:h(x)\le f(x)\text{ for all }x\in R\right\}
\end{align}\\~\\
\text{Prove that if $f:R\to\R$ is integrable, then}\\
\text{$
\begin{align}
\iint_R fdA=&\inf\left\{\iint_RgdA:g(x)\ge f(x)\text{ for all }x\in R\right\}\\
=&\sup\left\{\iint_RhdA:h(x)\le f(x)\text{ for all }x\in R\right\}
\end{align}$}}$

$~$(The question is from this [online note](http://www.math.toronto.edu/courses/mat237y1/20199/notes/Chapter4/S4.2.html#sect-4.2.P))

**My thought**

For the first direction of the first part, we assume that $f$ is integrable.

From the definition that means $f$ is bounded and we have
\begin{align}
&\iint_Rf(x)dA\\
=&\underline{\iint_R}f(x)dA&&=\overline{\iint_R}f(x)dA\\
=&\sup_PL_Pf&&=\inf_PU_Pf\\
=&\sup_P\sum_{i=1}^{JK}m_i\text{area}(R_i)&&=\inf_P\sum_{i=1}^{JK}M_i\text{area}(R_i)\\
=&\sup_P\sum_{i=1}^{JK}\inf\{f(x):x\in R_i\}\text{area}(R_i)&&=\inf_P\sum_{i=1}^{JK}\sup\{f(x):x\in R_i\}\text{area}(R_i)\\
=&\sup_P\sum_{i=1}^{JK}\inf\{f(x):x\in R_i\}(x_j-x_{j-1})(y_k-y_{k-1})&&=\inf_P\sum_{i=1}^{JK}\sup\{f(x):x\in R_i\}(x_j-x_{j-1})(y_k-y_{k-1})
\end{align}
However, I still can't tell how to conclude $$\inf\left\{\iint_RgdA:g(x)\ge f(x)\text{ for all }x\in R\right\}
=\sup\left\{\iint_RhdA:h(x)\le f(x)\text{ for all }x\in R\right\}$$
from this condition, and I don't get another direction too, could someone help me.